# intent.putExtra always reverts to boolean agurments

Tags: android, android-intent

My putExtra method needs to take a serializable object. I want to pass an instance of SQLiteOpenHelper to a new activity. I choose the putExtra method that takes a serializable argument, and once I enter my SQLiteOpenHelper instance as an argument, it says error because it needs to be boolean.

Code:

```
public void createProfile(View view) {
        Intent login = new Intent(this, CreateProfileActivity.class);
        login.putExtra("db", this.db);
        startActivity(login);
    }
```

Comment: Why would you want to pass an instance of `SQLiteOpenHelper` around? It is not meant to be used this way, I think...

Comment: @Szymon I thought it would use less resources to pass it, than to create a new one. I guess creating a new one in the new activity should be fine.

Comment: boolean just happens to be alphabetically first so that overload is picked when there isn't a specific match

Comment: Just create a new one. You should only pass pieces of data between activities, not helper classes like that.

Comment: Thanks @laalto, my class i am passing my need a serializable attribute.

Answer (score 3):

What should be passed between activities is data (packed into primitive types or more complex classes).

Helper classes like `SQLiteOpenHelper` are not meant to be passed around between activities. Create a new instance when you need it.

Comment: Yes I agree it is a horrible idea to pass around connection objects !